# Safari behavior dependent upon "inspect element" having been done?

Tags: jquery, forms, safari

A horrifically weird problem with Mac Safari (and iPad Safari, for that matter) --

I'm putting together a form that lets a user specify either a file input or a text string, but not both.  Thus, there is a radio button associated with each input; the form elements start off disabled, and, when one of the radio buttons is clicked, some jQuery runs and the disabled states are adjusted to let the user either select a file or enter some text.  This works correctly in Mac Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, and even, amazingly, IE 9.

No such luck in Safari:

- If I click on the radio button that should enable the file field, nothing seems to happen, although a console.log() suggests that the disabled attribute has been removed.
- If I click on the radio button that should enable the textfield, nothing happens to it, but the FILE FIELD widget (the "Choose..." button) flat out disappears.
- More clicking back and forth between the two radio buttons doesn't do anything.

***HOWEVER***, if, before I click on anything, I do an "Inspect Element" on the form area, everything works correctly.  Further, if I first click on the link field's radio button, such that the file field thing goes away, and THEN do "Inspect Element", the form redraws, showing proper views of both buttons and fields, and everything works correctly.

Gak.  There's a big hunk of code behind this, so I may or may not be able to get it out into a fiddle.  But my current belief is that I have somehow burrowed my way down into some really obscure Safari bug, and will have to do something to burrow my way out.  I guess I'm posting here in search of sympathy or something, and to see if anyone else, in the past, has stumbled into something similar.  Any takers? :)

Comment: I had a strange Safari error similar to this a while back.  Try triggering some things on it with jQuery - something that might give it focus / cause it to redraw.  In my case, `jQuery(el).css("border", "none");` did the trick (the thing didn't have a border in the first place, it just caused the element to get redrawn / fiddled with by the browser.

Comment: Good idea!, but no luck yet.  I'm still poking, though...

Comment: Score!  `$('form#form_id').css('display', 'none').css('display', 'block')`  There's probably a more refined selector I could be using here, but I'm happy.  If you make an answer version of your comment, I'll be happy to confirm it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a strange Safari error similar to this a while back.

The solution in my case was to trigger some things on elements with jQuery - something that might give it focus / cause it to redraw. In my case the following:

`jQuery(el).css("border", "none");`

did the trick.

The element didn't have a border in the first place, it just caused the element to get redrawn / fiddled with by the browser.